# Rewrite and redirect subdomain to other URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following subdomain (example):

```
subdomain.test.com
```

Now I want to redirect this subdomain to a IP-Address with port number:

```
123.123.123.123:1234/test
```

And the last thing is, that I want to keep the original URL in the edit field of the browser containing something like:

```
subdomain.test.com/test
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect a subdomain to another domain's subfolder and keep the subdomain's URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335217/redirect-a-subdomain-to-another-domains-subfolder-and-keep-the-subdomains-url)

Comment: @MrTux I tried it and get reconnected to my spqcified URL, but how can I get step number 3 to work (hide URL)? Can you show me an example?

Comment: What's step 3? [P] should do the trick. Edit the question and show what you have so far.